# How to change breakpoint values in primevue/primefaces?

Tags: css, primefaces, breakpoints, primevue

How can I change the default breakpoint values in primevue/primefaces ?

I mean setting values different than 576px for xs, 768px for md, 992px for lg etc.

A similar question has been asked [here](https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=49710) 3 years ago but no one answered.

Comment: How is this both PrimeVue and PrimeFaces related?

Comment: PrimeVue is the Vue version of PrimeFaces, I'm looking for a solution on PrimeVue but a generic solution on PrimeFaces that could be applied to PrimeVue, PrimeReact and PrimeNG could also work in my case

Answer (score 1):

After spending some time trying to come up with a solution, I've decided to go with this approach:

> Import this css after you import your Primevue styles. Be sure to use
> @media in the order it is provided below.

**

> This will override Primevue's breakpoints

**

Lemme know if you found a better approach.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 0px){
    .p-xs-1 {
        width: 8.3333%;
    }
    .p-xs-2 {
        width: 16.6667%;
    }
    .p-xs-3 {
        width: 25%;
    }
    .p-xs-4 {
        width: 33.3333%;
    }
    .p-xs-5 {
        width: 41.6667%;
    }
    .p-xs-6 {
        width: 50%;
    }
    .p-xs-7 {
        width: 58.3333%;
    }
    .p-xs-8 {
        width: 66.6667%;
    }
    .p-xs-9 {
        width: 75%;
    }
    .p-xs-10 {
        width: 83.3333%;
    }
    .p-xs-11 {
        width: 91.6667%;
    }
    .p-xs-12 {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 576px){
    .p-sm-1 {
        width: 8.3333%;
    }
    .p-sm-2 {
        width: 16.6667%;
    }
    .p-sm-3 {
        width: 25%;
    }
    .p-sm-4 {
        width: 33.3333%;
    }
    .p-sm-5 {
        width: 41.6667%;
    }
    .p-sm-6 {
        width: 50%;
    }
    .p-sm-7 {
        width: 58.3333%;
    }
    .p-sm-8 {
        width: 66.6667%;
    }
    .p-sm-9 {
        width: 75%;
    }
    .p-sm-10 {
        width: 83.3333%;
    }
    .p-sm-11 {
        width: 91.6667%;
    }
    .p-sm-12 {
        width: 100%;
    }
}


@media screen and (min-width: 992px){
    .p-md-1 {
        width: 8.3333%;
    }
    .p-md-2 {
        width: 16.6667%;
    }
    .p-md-3 {
        width: 25%;
    }
    .p-md-4 {
        width: 33.3333%;
    }
    .p-md-5 {
        width: 41.6667%;
    }
    .p-md-6 {
        width: 50%;
    }
    .p-md-7 {
        width: 58.3333%;
    }
    .p-md-8 {
        width: 66.6667%;
    }
    .p-md-9 {
        width: 75%;
    }
    .p-md-10 {
        width: 83.3333%;
    }
    .p-md-11 {
        width: 91.6667%;
    }
    .p-md-12 {
        width: 100%;
    }
}


@media screen and (min-width: 1200px){
    .p-lg-1 {
        width: 8.3333%;
    }
    .p-lg-2 {
        width: 16.6667%;
    }
    .p-lg-3 {
        width: 25%;
    }
    .p-lg-4 {
        width: 33.3333%;
    }
    .p-lg-5 {
        width: 41.6667%;
    }
    .p-lg-6 {
        width: 50%;
    }
    .p-lg-7 {
        width: 58.3333%;
    }
    .p-lg-8 {
        width: 66.6667%;
    }
    .p-lg-9 {
        width: 75%;
    }
    .p-lg-10 {
        width: 83.3333%;
    }
    .p-lg-11 {
        width: 91.6667%;
    }
    .p-lg-12 {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1600px){
    .p-xl-1 {
        width: 8.3333%;
    }
    .p-xl-2 {
        width: 16.6667%;
    }
    .p-xl-3 {
        width: 25%;
    }
    .p-xl-4 {
        width: 33.3333%;
    }
    .p-xl-5 {
        width: 41.6667%;
    }
    .p-xl-6 {
        width: 50%;
    }
    .p-xl-7 {
        width: 58.3333%;
    }
    .p-xl-8 {
        width: 66.6667%;
    }
    .p-xl-9 {
        width: 75%;
    }
    .p-xl-10 {
        width: 83.3333%;
    }
    .p-xl-11 {
        width: 91.6667%;
    }
    .p-xl-12 {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 2000px){
    .p-xxl-1 {
        width: 8.3333%;
    }
    .p-xxl-2 {
        width: 16.6667%;
    }
    .p-xxl-3 {
        width: 25%;
    }
    .p-xxl-4 {
        width: 33.3333%;
    }
    .p-xxl-5 {
        width: 41.6667%;
    }
    .p-xxl-6 {
        width: 50%;
    }
    .p-xxl-7 {
        width: 58.3333%;
    }
    .p-xxl-8 {
        width: 66.6667%;
    }
    .p-xxl-9 {
        width: 75%;
    }
    .p-xxl-10 {
        width: 83.3333%;
    }
    .p-xxl-11 {
        width: 91.6667%;
    }
    .p-xxl-12 {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

[image]